# How to call procedures from hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I am new to hibernate I would like to know can we call procedures from hibernate or not. If we can call can any please give me some example .(my procedures will have  multiple out parameters )

Comment: Yes, this is possible.  Have you looked around before posting?  (see [here](https://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/how-to-call-store-procedure-in-hibernate/) for an example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you have to get current session and begin transaction:

```
session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
```

Next you create stored procedure with method `createStoredProcedureQuery`. It accepts procedure name("`listPhones`") as argument:

```
StoredProcedureQuery procedure = session.createStoredProcedureQuery("listPhones");
```

Next you need to register all in and out parameters. Use method `registerStoredProcedureParameter` . Its first arg is parameter index starting at 0, second arg is java type for sql type. Sql `varchar` is `String` in java. Third parameter is 
`javax.persistence.ParameterMode` enum. It can be `IN` or `OUT`, `INOUT`,`REF_CURSOR`.

```
procedure.registerStoredProcedureParameter(0, String.class, ParameterMode.IN);
procedure.registerStoredProcedureParameter(1, String.class, ParameterMode.OUT);
```

Finally you have to set registered parameters by index:

```
    procedure.setParameter(0, "22222287832,33333287832");
procedure.setParameter(1, string);
```